# get my function to loop through the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Hey guys so I am trying to do something and I am not sure how to go about it. I am working on a site for my fraternity. We have this HUGE array with all the bros info in it. I want a function that will loop through the array. Grab the data from column 2 and then write it to the page. but when it writes it it adds a link to it. my example out put would be. that way it can put all the images on the page.

I am trying to run it in the console but I do not think it is looping through the array and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone please advise?

```js
function imgTag(data) {
  var url = 'http://fratsite.com/images/'+data[1];
  return "<img src='"+url+"' width='392' height='400' alt='' />";
}

var output = document.write(imgTag);

console.log(output.join(''));
```

```html
var foo = new Array();
foo[0] = ["Brother-0001","0001.jpg"];
foo[1] = ["Brother-0002","0002.jpg"];
foo[2] = ["Brother-0003","0003.jpg"];
foo[3] = ["Brother-0004","0004.jpg"];
foo[4] = ["Brother-0005","0005.jpg"];
foo[5] = ["Brother-0006","0006.jpg"];
foo[6] = ["Brother-0007","0007.jpg"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer to use an array of Arrays rather than an array of Objects:

```
var imageForBro = function(bro){
   var name = bro.name,
       file = bro.image,
       path = 'http://fraternity.com/images/' + file;

   return "<img src='"+path+"' target='_blank'/>";
}

var bros = new Array();
bros[0] = ["Brother-0001","0001.jpg"];
bros[1] = ["Brother-0002","0002.jpg"];
bros[2] = ["Brother-0003","0003.jpg"];
bros[3] = ["Brother-0004","0004.jpg"];
bros[4] = ["Brother-0005","0005.jpg"];
bros[5] = ["Brother-0006","0006.jpg"];
bros[6] = ["Brother-0007","0007.jpg"];


for(var index in bros){
   var broData = bros[index],
       broName = broData[0],
       broImgFile = broData[1],
       imageEl = imageForBro(broImgFile);

   document.write(imageEl);  
}
```

And if you wanted to convert your Array to an array of Objects that would be easier to work with...

```
var arrayOfBroObjects = [];
for(var index in bros){
    var broData = bros[index],
        brother = {
           name : broData[0],
           image: broData[1]
        };

    arrayOfBroObjects.push(brother);
}
```

Now it's an Array of Objects! Then you could use JSON to encode/decode it for later use:

```
// encode the array in JSON notation as a string
broJson = JSON.stringify(arrayOfBroObjects);

// decode the JSON notation string into a JavaScrpt array
arrayOfBroObjects = JSON.parse(broJson);
```

Also, you might want to look into using a JavaScript library such as jQuery, it will make your life easier when building a full-fledged website.

Comment: That can be something we look into in the future however the array already exists. and it has about 1600 rows in it. So i dont think changing the array would really work now.

Comment: Typically in JavaScript you'd want to use an Array of Objects, and you could definitely convert your existing array to Objects no problemo-- but I've updated my answer regardless!

Answer (score 0):

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
  var url = 'http://fratsite.com/images/'+item[1];
  document.write("<img src='"+url+"' width='392' height='400' alt='' />");
});
```

That should do what you're looking for.

What is wrong with your code? You're not looping on the array. You appear to be only accessing one array item in your `imgTag` function, then returning the formatted string. Then when you try to assign `output` to `document.write(imgTag)`, you've already written it to the document, and `output` is assigned the return value of `document.write()`, which is nothing.

I also recommend using JQuery. It will make life much easier for you.

Comment: I thought that was straight forward but it keeps throwing an error data is not defined

Comment: `data` in this case is the array. So for you it would be `foo`

Answer (score 0):

an alternative solution if you want to insert some additional tags between each image tag:

```
document.write(foo.map(function(data){
    var url = 'http://fratsite.com/images/'+data[1];
    return "<img src='"+url+"' width='392' height='400' alt='' />";
}).join('<br/>'));
```